# the meaning behind the code in /dev/bus/usb/xxx/yyy?

Tags: linux, usb

```
lakhal@lakhal-ThinkPad-T430s:~$ hexdump -C  /dev/bus/usb/003/014
00000000  12 01 00 02 e0 00 00 40  e8 04 63 68 ff ff 02 03  |.......@..ch....|
00000010  04 01 09 02 4b 00 02 01  00 c0 30 08 0b 00 02 e0  |....K.....0.....|
00000020  01 03 07 09 04 00 00 01  e0 01 03 05 05 24 00 10  |.............$..|
00000030  01 05 24 01 00 01 04 24  02 00 05 24 06 00 01 07  |..$....$...$....|
00000040  05 83 03 08 00 09 09 04  01 00 02 0a 00 00 06 07  |................|
00000050  05 81 02 00 02 00 07 05  02 02 00 02 00           |.............|
0000005d
```

Comment: Please, make a reproducible example.

Comment: I didn't understand , what do you mean by "reproducible example" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file allows you to read certain USB descriptors from the device.  The USB device descriptor, which is defined by the USB specification, is located at the beginning of the file.

For more details, see the file `usb/core/devio.c` in the source code of your kernel.  In particular, look at the function `usbdev_read`, which implements the kernel side of the `read` system call for these special files.  I cannot find official documentation at the moment.

I believe some parts of the file are "holes", meaning that you won't be able to read any data from them, and you might get meaningless data depending on whether the program you uses initializes the buffers it uses for reading from the file.

Comment: What do you mean?  If my answer is satisfactory can you upvote it or click the checkmark to accept it?